# Oracle row-wise summing

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have stored procedure which returns a category-wise data in a group. Now the problem is I need to sum the category-wise data for a group and insert it at the beginning of a category. For example:

```
Group   Category    X1  X2  X3  X4
========================================================
A       A1          1   1   1   1
----------------------------------------------------
A       A2          1   1   1   1
---------------------------------------------------
B       B1          1   1   1   1
----------------------------------------------------
B       B2          1   1   1   1
----------------------------------------------------
```

Should be displayed as:

```
Group   Category    X1  X2  X3  X4
=======================================================
A           A       2   2   2   2
----------------------------------------------------
A           A1      1   1   1   1
----------------------------------------------------
A           A2      1   1   1   1
----------------------------------------------------
B           B       2   2   2   2
----------------------------------------------------
B           B1      1   1   1   1
----------------------------------------------------
B           B2      1   1   1   1
----------------------------------------------------
```

All this needs to be done in a single procedure. I cannot use temp table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you just want something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT group, category, x1, x2, x3, x4
      FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT group, group, sum(x1), sum(x2), sum(x3), sum(x4)
      FROM your_table
     GROUP BY group
    )
 ORDER BY group, category
```

Of course, you'd need to use your actual column names-- 'GROUP`is a reserved word so you cannot have a column named`GROUP'.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm fetching the data from multiple table and joining it to get the data.  It's not single table.

Comment: @user2435260 - OK.  So what's the problem?  Presumably, you simplified the problem that you posted to involve a single table knowing that you can then just replace the table reference with an inline view that implements whatever joins your actual data has.  So you just need to do that with each of the answers that have been posted.

Answer (score 3):

You can perform multiple levels of aggregation with a GROUP BY ROLLUP(), including no aggregation at all:

```
select
  grp,
  coalesce(cat,grp) cat,
  sum(x1),
  sum(x2),
  sum(x3),
  sum(x4)
from
  my_table
group by grp,
  rollup(cat)
order by
  grp,
  cat nulls first;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d9c4/8

Comment: Cheers. Everytime I use group by rollup or cube I have to fiddle around with the damned things to get them to work though -- can't keep the logic in my head.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select 
    * 
from YourTable
union all
select 
    "Group", "Group" as Category, 
    SUM(X1), 
    SUM(X2),
    SUM(X3),
    SUM(X4)
from YourTable
Group by "Group"
order by "Group", Category
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm fetching the data from multiple table and joining it to get the data.  It's not single table